# GIT Website Delopyment including submodules

Tags: git, deployment

So I got a GIT repository with a couple of submodules.
Now i created a "post-update" hook on my webserver that automatically deploys my website on update.

That's how my post-update hook looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf /home/my_user/public_html/my_website/*
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/my_user/public_html/my_website/
export GIT_DIR=/home/my_user/gitrepos/my_website.git
git checkout -f
```

Everything works nicely apart from the fact that the submodules directories are not exported...
And that is my question. How can I deploy a GIT repository and it's submodules through the post-update hook?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I made a script that avoids the use of a non-bare repository and receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore

```
#!/bin/sh

# DIR VARS
DIR_GIT="/home/my_user/gitrepos/my_repo.git"
DIR_HTTP="/home/my_user/public_html/my_website"

unset GIT_DIR

# Recreate HTTP dir
rm -rf $DIR_HTTP
mkdir $DIR_HTTP

# Clone git repository
git clone $DIR_GIT $DIR_HTTP

# import submodules
cd $DIR_HTTP
git init --bare $DIR_HTTP
git submodule init
git submodule update

# delete unnecessary git repository in http dir
rm -rf $DIR_HTTP/.git
```

Any improvements are welcome

Comment: Nice feedback, more practical than my own answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

It should work, except you could add, for taking care of those submodules:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

See also [Using git submodule update --init on a post hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593467/using-git-submodule-update-init-on-a-post-hook) if you have error messages.